# form username and database username not agreeing even though they are the same

Tags: php, mysql, blowfish

I'm trying to create a login using blowfish, PHP and MySQL

I have a user setup in the database and have entered the same info in the form. By checking with echo, the code goes as far as the if statement(see they do not match (i.e. it goes into the if statement and fails with password as it does not have the correct user (using !=)
A fresh pair of eyes would be great.

Thanks

PHP code

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM 'users' WHERE LOWER('username')=:username";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':username',strtolower ($_POST['username']));
$stmt->execute();


if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
{
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    require('blowfish.php');
    require('bcrypt.class.php');
    $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
        if($bcrypt->verify($_POST['password'],$row['password']))
    {
        echo"logged in!! fish";
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form method="POST" action="authorise.php">
Username: <input type ="text" name="username"/><br/>
Password: <input type ="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't treat your table and column as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need single quotes in your query

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username)=:username";
```

You might need to use backticks on column name and table name if you are using any reserved keyword. Quotes are instead used when you use strings in your query to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM 'users' WHERE LOWER('username')=:username";
```

Using the single quote inside the LOWER function essentially is asking MySQL if parameter username is equal to the literal string username instead of the column named username.  IE if `$_POST['username']` equals "robbert", your query is asking does robbert=username.  No, it equals robbert. Same is true for the table. Either use backticks or no quotes at all.

In MySQL backticks (`) are used to quote a column or table name.  This should be the query you want to use

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username)=:username";
```

Comment: Hi, does that mean that I do not use ':username' and use $_POST['username']. Also changing the select statement: $query = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username)=:username";. Thanks for your help

Comment: No, you want to keep `:username` in your query and use the `bindParam` method to minimize SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Bcrypt::verify() in C:\xampp\htdocs\newlogin\authorise.php on line 27. The line in question is:if($bcrypt->verify($_POST['password'],$row['password'])), thanks if you can help I really appreciate

Comment: Your bcrypt object doesn't include a method called verify.